# Create a Chips Dropdown in Google Sheet using Apps Script

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I have an Apps Script code that dynamically creates a dropdown depending on another one, but the generated dropdown has no chips:

[image]

Is there any way I can customize the dropdown style within Apps Script?

The code is the following:

```js
function onEdit() {
  var monthTabs = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

  var aCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();

  if (aColumn == 4 && monthTabs.includes(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName())) {
    var cellContent = aCell.getValue();
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);

    if (cellContent == "") {
      range.clearDataValidations();
    }
    else {
      var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(cellContent);
      var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sourceRange, true).build();
      range.setDataValidation(rule);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be achieved but it is a workaround rather than a good method to use. It takes advantage of the fact that range.copyTo will also copy the chip styling to the destination cell. I've setup a demonstration sheet based on the code you've provided, but it probably wants reworking to suit your actual situation.

Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fTUd85YY9GUNgLPOPDHisIpUiPllgz829EuFOR_k8V0/edit?usp=sharing

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var monthTabs = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

  var aCell = e.range;

  if (aCell.getColumn() === 4 && monthTabs.includes(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName())) {
    var cellContent = aCell.getDisplayValue();
    var range = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aCell.getColumn() + 1);

    if (cellContent === "") {
      range.clearDataValidations();
    }
    else {
      switch(e.source.getActiveSheet().getName()) {
        case "Jan":
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("JanChip").copyTo(range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION, false);
          break;
        case "Feb":
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName("FebChip").copyTo(range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION, false);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I struggle describing the process in text, so please take a look through the spreadsheet if you need to understand more. It does make use of named ranges and a helper sheet.

Edited to include the CopyPasteType in the script as this will avoid conditional formatting issues.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there's no way to customize the datavalidation dropdown style using Google apps script or Google sheets api. You may request this feature [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113)

Answer (score 0):

Still looking for solution to change the chip colors using app script. Thank you to @Dreadnotic to getting us closer.

The only edit I would make is removing that switch statement to accomplish the same result

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var monthTabs = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

 var aCell = e.range;

 if (aCell.getColumn() === 4 && monthTabs.includes(sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName())) {
  var cellContent = aCell.getDisplayValue();
  var range = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aCell.getColumn() + 1);

  if (cellContent === "") {
   range.clearDataValidations();
  }
  else {
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(sheetName + "Chip").copyTo(range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_DATA_VALIDATION, false);
  }
 }
}
```